# Method is called twice in StreamBuilder which contains custom dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, stream-builder

- I create a loading dialog and put it in StreamBuilder. At the same time, there is a method named `_loadingText` as the dialog parameter. When I click the 'Go Run' button, the `_loadingText` method is called twice.
- As the same way, I used the flutter build-in dialog `showAboutDialog`, everything is OK.
- If I remove the StreamBuilder, the `_loadingText` is called once too.

It takes me one day!!!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...

- main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:view_animation/loading_dialog.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamController<String> _streamController;

  TextEditingController _inputController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

    _inputController = TextEditingController();
    _inputController.addListener(() {
      _streamController.add(_inputController.text);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _streamController.close();
  }

  String _loadingText() {
    print('===== 2. Method run OVER =====');
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          _inputContainer(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
            ),
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _streamController.stream.map((text) => text.length > 4),
              builder: (context, snap) {
                return FlatButton(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFAC0B),
                  disabledColor: Colors.black12,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 12.5),
                  onPressed: snap.data != null && snap.data
                      ? () {
                          print('===== 1. show dialog =====');
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return LoadingDialog(
                                  loadingText: _loadingText(),
                                );
                              });
                          // showAboutDialog(context: context, applicationName: _loadingText());
                        }
                      : null,
                  child: Text(
                    'GO RUN',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _inputContainer() {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFAC0B),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        controller: _inputController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLines: 1,
        cursorColor: Colors.orange,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Let's GO",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- loading_dialog.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoadingDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final String loadingText; 
  final bool outsideDismiss; 

  final Function dismissCallback;
  final Future<dynamic> requestCallback;

  LoadingDialog(
      {Key key,
      this.loadingText = "Loading...",
      this.outsideDismiss = true,
      this.dismissCallback,
      this.requestCallback,
      })
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoadingDialogState createState() => _LoadingDialogState();
}

class _LoadingDialogState extends State<LoadingDialog> {

  void _dismissDialog(){
    if(widget.dismissCallback != null) {
      widget.dismissCallback();
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
     print('===== 3. loading init =====');
    if (widget.requestCallback != null) {
      widget.requestCallback.then((_) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.outsideDismiss ? _dismissDialog : null,
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 120.0,
            height: 120.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20.0,
                    ),
                    child: new Text(
                      widget.loadingText,
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- [log gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2Dk.gif)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you tap on button first time your TextField is still active that means new state comes and flutter rebuilds itself. When you tap on button second your Textfield is inactive.

Comment: Thanks @Temirlan. Maybe you are right. But I used `showAboutDialog` as the same way, the method was called only once.

Answer (score 0):

The points are when you pass the function to the **onTap** widget it's going to execute when it building state and calling a function without tapping on it:

So instead of a passing method to the **OnTap**, try something like this:

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () widget.outsideDismiss ? ()
      {
      this._dismissDialog();
      } : null,
      ...
```